# how to trigger the same job again with different parameter value when it fails for one time?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I need to trigger the same job again with different parameter value when it fails. But i don't want to trigger the same if it is a triggered run due to failure. How can I handle it ?

Comment: Do you have some code? What kind of parameters do you want to pass?

Comment: @JustAProgrammer I am executing a python script which can take some arguments. All are string parameter to the python script.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
try {
    build job: 'PayloadJob', parameters: [
              //some param
          ]
} catch (Exception e) {
    build job: 'PayloadJob', parameters: [
              //other param
          ]
}
```

If you would need to trigger itself just set some extra parameter to figure out that you were started after failure.

Answer (score 0):

This example show how to trigger the same job with parameter that specify is it rebuild 
or not and trigger the job if the build is fail for any reason.

```
pipeline{
    agent any
    stages{
        stage('do something'){
            steps{
                script{
                    if(rebuild == "no"){
                        // this is to demonstrate how it's work.
                        currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                    }else{
                        println "success"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        failure {
            // To prevent endless loop in case the nested build fails,
            // trigger nested job only if it's not a rebuild . 
            if(rebuild == "no"){
                println "On failure"
                build job:"TestStep" ,
                     propagate: true, //Set current job to failure if nested job fail. 
                     parameters:[string(name:'rebuild ',value:"yes")]
            }
        }
    }
}
```